# google places api how to get

Tags: android, google-places-api

can any one please tell me how to get the Google places api key and what is the API of Google places. ex."com.Google.android.maps" for Google maps similarly for Google places what is it

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ go here and read those doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find the detail regarding the Google Place API :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/

This is a tutorial how to use it :

http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/

This may help as well :

http://ddewaele.blogspot.in/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html

and

http://www.claytical.com/blog/android-dynamic-autocompletion-using-google-places-api

Comment: thanks a lot. but in that documentation they are talking about Google api key but i m getting only "Cliend id " and all.when i m trying to start the Google places service it is asking website url and in API ACCESS i m not getting the API key in Simple API Access section

Answer (score 0):

go to that url :-

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/
```

here everything is mentioned..

may be this will be helpful to u..

Comment: thanks a lot. but in that documentation they are talking about Google api key but i m getting only "Cliend id " and all.when i m trying to start the Google places service it is asking website url and in API ACCESS i m not getting the API key in Simple API Access section

Answer (score 0):

I have used Places API in my Project. The best way to get all the information about Places API is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) of it. The main purpose of Places API is to get the near by places information using the keywords. Basically it is a service that gives you information about places. Go through the doc of it, its a self explanatory.

For more reference refer [this](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks a lot. but in that documentation they are talking about Google api key but i m getting only "Cliend id " and all.when i m trying to start the Google places service it is asking website url and in API ACCESS i m not getting the API in Simple API Access section.

Comment: Read the doc carefully. in the Authentication section they have provided the API KEY url that is Google Console. You need to create one project in that after that you will get the API Key.

Comment: In the authentication section they have mentioned but in the console its not providing the API key its only providing cliend id and client secret....

Comment: I got the keys from there itself. How that i don't remember right now. Let me check that if i got anything i will let you know...

Answer (score 0):

You need to [login Google API console and create an API key for yourself
http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/06/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key/](http://code.google.com/)